# Add Array in Javascript which ouput matches the parameter content

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
let arr = [90, 80, 70]
function addArray (num){
  console.log(arr.push(num));
  }
 addArray([30,50]);
```

how should i fix my code if i want make a output: [90,80,70,30,50]

Comment: You haven't found an explanation on how to iterate over the elements of an array and how to add elements to an array?

Comment: `if(num instanceof Array) arr.push(...num); else arr.push(num);` - will spread values of num if it's an array, otherwise, num as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Array.prototype.concat` instead.

The function `push` adds a value or values.

```js
let arr = [90, 80, 70]
function addArray (num) {
  return arr.concat(num);
}
console.log(addArray([30,50]));
```

If you want to use `push`, you should use the `spread operator` as follow:

```js
let arr = [90, 80, 70]
function addArray (num) {
  arr.push(...num);
}
addArray([30,50])
console.log(arr);
```